# similarities and differences between FIteagle and OpenIot frameworks

Tags: frameworks, iot

I m trying to understand better the two frameworks therfore i m trying to figure out the similarities and differences between FIteagle framework and OpenIot because both of the frameworks includes the same aims, the first one provides a testbeds environments which provide different resources to manage and communicate with and the second one provides the possiblity to connect to different sensors within a database cloud and it provide the ability to communicate with the sensors and to aply some IoT services on it. Does anyone has an idea about the two frameworks ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are still interesting and making research in this area and looking for a detailed comparative and understanding of the two frameworks, I published a paper in this matter which contain a specific and a complete understanding of both frameworks. Since the paper is not uploaded yet to the internet Please get in touch with me in case you want to read it.
I will provide a link here as soon as I upload it.

Answer (score 0):

Not being familiar with any of the above frameworks, I would say that eventually all IoT frameworks will focus on virtual markets in order to deliver industry-specific services. Consider transportation and smart grids - those are completely separate industries. for example, in transportation - geo analytics is much more important than in smart grids where meters tend to have fixed locations.

Comment: thanks for your answer @Sergei, but i was hopping to get more specific answer regarding both frameworks for example the way they communicat and react with the resources connected and so on.Do you have an idea ?

Comment: I haven't interacted with those frameworks, but you might want to check out bluemix from ibm. The reason I'm suggesting it is mostly because IBM documentation is typically comprehensive and include high level overviews. In case of bluemix, the devices communicate to message brokers via mqtt protocol that provides asynchronous bi-directional communication (pub/sub).